# O que exatamente é necessário para publicar no Google plus com suas APIs

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus

Minha pergunta é sobre o [Google + Domains API:](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/)

A partir desta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272963/how-to-post-on-google-plus-pages-through-api#answer-14278367) é dito: "Atualmente, não há API pública para publicar no Google+".

Então, procure outras perguntas e respostas, vejo a possibilidade de POST com Google + Domains API através da conta de domínio do Google.

Então, novamente, surgiram muitas dúvidas:

1- Qual é a conta do Google Domain e como definir isso para o propósito de postar no Google Plus (Perfil / Página ou Comunidades)?

Eu aprendo sobre [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) e [git google respositore php class library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service/PlusDomains).

Em alguns testes (do localhost), obtive autorização e acessoToken, mas sempre com erros como esse no final: Credenciais proibidas ou inválidas.

Nas minhas pesquisas, o erro é porque não uso Google Domain Acccount.

Então eu não vejo em todos os resultados do Google a maneira de fazer isso de ponta a ponta, de criar o Google Account Domain para POST no Google Plus.

Eu não estou pedindo um tutorial completo, apenas o caminho para um eu faço isso.

Após 5 dias consecutivos, aqui está a minha última tentativa (ou não, quem sabe), mas estou cansado e não consigo ver a luz no final do túnel.

Todas as dicas são bem-vindas.